# Property 'getName' does not exist on type 'C'

Tags: typescript

```
function A(constructor: Function) {
    constructor.prototype.getAge = (age: number) => {
        return age
    }
}

function B(constructor: Function) {
    constructor.prototype.getName = (name: string) => {
        return name
    }
}


@A
@B
class C {

}

const c = new C();

// Here you will see error
console.log(c.getAge(10));
// @ts-ignore
console.log(c.getName("Andrew"))
```

I want to add some functionality by using `decorators` , as you can see on example above , but typescript say me that functions I add doesn't exist on my `C` class instance , but it actually exist when i will do `// @ts-ignore` and with execute this code, it will return me value. What can I prevent loosing typing , without making `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: Please read [this](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-inheritance/) and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), and explain in your question why what you're doing is different and what you expect to accomplish with it.  Also read https://xyproblem.info

Comment: Decorators cannot mutate the *type* of classes in TypeScript (this is a longstanding limitation in TS).  You can work around this by using strongly-typed mixins instead, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m04Onm) perhaps.  Does that address your question fully (and I can write up an answer) or am I missing something

Comment: I want to add some functionality to my class , without inheritence , but by using decorators, what is a problem here ? can you answer on my question directly ? @RobertHarvey

Comment: @jcalz, yes , I was also thinking about mixins , but decorators approach looks more convinient and readable

Comment: See [ms/TS#48885](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48885) and [ms/TS#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) for what's going on with decorators and mutations.  In short, you can't do it in TS.  Do you want an answer that just says "no, sorry" with a link to these issues?  Or do you want an answer that gives mixins as a workaround?

Comment: @jcalz , I think it will be usefull for someone who will want to get answer on same question , to describe it both